# Get-ADuser to locate all group membership output

Tags: powershell

I have used a pretty good script but have one major issue for my excel or CSV output. The output *will not* display the `Domain Users` listing as seen when looking in AD.

All objects or `Name` is in place for everything else but refuses to list the `Domain Users` group.

```
$alist = "Name`tAccountName`tDescription`tEmailAddress`tLastLogonDate`tManager`tTitle`tDepartment`tCompany`twhenCreated`tAcctEnabled`tGroups`n"
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Manager,Title,Department,Company,whenCreated,Enabled,MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Name
$userlist | ForEach-Object {
    $grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object
    $arec = $_.Name,$_.SamAccountName,$_.Description,$_.EmailAddress,$_LastLogonDate,$_.Manager,$_.Title,$_.Department,$_.Company,$_.whenCreated,$_.Enabled
    $aline = ($arec -join "`t") + "`t" + ($grps -join "`t") + "`n"
    $alist += $aline
}
$alist | Out-File C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\InclusiveADUsers.csv
```

Comment: 1) That is by design if `Domain Users` is the primary group. 2) Don't forget to ask your question. 3) There's no need to build your own character-separated strings. `Export-Csv` is much easier to use and your code will be a lot easier to read.

Comment: What do you see on the console if you put a `Write-Host $aline`  just before `$alist += $aline`?

Comment: Have you considered using ``Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t"``?

Comment: To get the primary group for a user you can do `Get-ADUser -Identity $adUser -Properties PrimaryGroup | Select-Object PrimaryGroup`